# Samba: Oops! Unhandled error message: invalid argument

Tags: samba

On Ubuntu 18.04 accessing samba share on a linux machine. After reboot I can access the samba shared folders, but after several hours I get this error message and I have to reboot.

How to fix it?

Comment: What's your question? how to fix it?

Comment: Yes. And how to prevent it.